# saga pattern: what about if compensation action fails

Tags: microservices, saga

We're trying to understand how to compensate a "saga compensation failure".

We have two microservices, and two databases, one per microservice.

1. Customer microservice
2. Contract microservice

Use case: Customer alias modification.

1. Request is sent to `"Customer microservice"`.
   a. `Customer` alias is modified on customer table, but its state is `pending`.
   b. A `customer modified` event is sent.
2. `customer modified` event is received by `"Constract microservice"`.
   a. Received `Customer` is updated on all contracts (we're using mongodb), since customer information is embedded in each contract.
   b. A `contract updated` event is sent.
3. `contract updated` event is received by `"Customer microservice"`.
   a. `Customer`'s state is set to `confirmed`.

If `3.a` fails a compensation action is performed, but what about if it fails?

Answer (score 0):

This can be handle with combination of below approaches:

1. Implement Retry pattern for Compensate Action
2. Exception handling - exception can be save and, this can be resolve  through - Automated process like Retry mechanism through separate application
3. This is extension of approach#2, If Automated process unable to resolve, generate exception report which can be review manually and action can be taken based on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the term saga but you really mean you want a transaction. If you really need a transaction do that (you can look at solutions like https://docs.temporal.io/ for providing that)
[personally [I think transactions between services are bad](https://arnon.me/2010/09/soa-antipattern-transactional-integration/), and if I need transaction between services, I try to rethink my design but your milage may vary]

You didn't specify the reason on why contracts would reject the change - if there are business rules that one thing but if these are "technical reasons" like availability etc. then the thing to do is to make sure the event is persistent and was sent (e.g. like outbox pattern on the sending side) and have the consuming service(s) handle it when it can

If there are business rules involved then maybe it is a bad example but I'd expect a person can still change their alias regardless and the compensation would be keeping some of the contracts with the old alias or something a long these lines.

by the way, it seems you have a design issue that causes needless temporal coupling between your services.

If the alias is important in contracts but owned by the customers service, the alias stored in the contracts should be considered as cached.
In this case the customers service can close the update regardless of what other services do. it can fire the event and you can complete the process when you can on the contracts service. when a contract is read you can check if there's a newer version of the customer and if so get it. you may also (depending on the business reqs. specify that the data is correct as of the last update)

Comment: Thanks Arnon. I've written another question expanding according your comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120242/saga-pattern-is-necessary-for-caching-purposes).

Answer (score -1):

[BASE VS ACID](https://www.infoq.com/articles/saga-orchestration-outbox/) :

ISOLATION: As local transactions are committed while the Saga is running, their changes are already visible to other concurrent transactions, despite the possibility that the Saga will fail eventually, causing all previously applied transactions to be compensated. I.e., from the perspective of the overall Saga, the isolation level is comparable to “read uncommitted.”

Eventually other services will read those inconsistent events, they will also take wrong decisions according to these, they will increase the number of events which should not be happen at all.

In the end there will be tons of events to rollback (how is that possible if your system let users to do more than allowed in real world ? Can you get back an ice cream from a kid which is sold 5 minute ago !)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).